# Download a .pdf and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, redirect, download

```
<a href="voucher.pdf">Download The Voucher</a>
```

So I have this voucher that the user can download but after that, it needs to redirect to another page. What would be a good way around this issue and something that is compatible on most browsers?

Comment: Is it plain JavaScript or are you using any framework/library?

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle Plain javascript

Answer (score 2):

Three steps for this:

1.Add the **"download"** attribute to the link tag which tells the browser that you don't want to follow the path to your pdf file but download it instead.

```
<a href="#" download>Download The Voucher</a>
```

2.Add an **onclick** event listener to your link tag.

```
const link = document.querySelector("a");
link.onclick = goSomewhere
```

3.Modify the window.location.href to your desire destination url

```
const goSomewhere = () => { window.location.href = "https://yourURL"}
```

Alternatively you can trigger a redirect using **window.location.replace** which in this case will send the proper HEADER HTTP request as if it were a normal redirect whereas changing the "href" will behave like a regular link.

Answer (score 1):

you could add onclick on <a>, something like

```
<a href="voucher.pdf" onclick="openTab()">Download The Voucher</a>
```

and on a js file or inside <script>

```
function openTab() {
    window.open('url');
}
```

on `'url'` you can insert an external or internal page